# Keep receiving error: "Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'"

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Everytime I try and send my parameters over to `Invoke-RestMethod` I always receive the error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "{
    "Content-Type":  "application/json",
    "Authorization":  "\"ZmY2ZTZiYjEtNmM5Mi00MzAyLWJjM2MtY2ZhYmFlOWVlNDE0OzIwMkI0MzdBNjExODQxQTA7MDAwMDAwMDJGRkNCRkJFREE1QzUyMUExNzFDNEJFMUNEMEYxMUM
2OTEzQTRERkMwNEExRkU3MjZBRDkyMDAxMjcwN0Q1RTQ0MDAwMDAwMDA7\""

}" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary"..
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Uploadv6.4.ps1
```

I've converted my variables to JSON format and now I'm lost as to what I need to do.

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]";

$seckey = MyPAMLogin $username $password;
$headers.Add("Authorization", $seckey);
$headers.Add("Content-Type", $contentType);
$seckey = $seckey | ConvertTo-Json
$headers = $headers | ConvertTo-Json;

$newAccount = [ordered]@{
    safe = $safeName;
    platformID = $platformID;
    username = $username;
    AccountName = $AccountName;
    password = "abc";
    secretType = "key";
    secret = "";
    platformAccountProperties = {};
    DisableAutoMgmt = $disableAutoMgmtReason;
    DisableAutoMgmtReason = $disableAutoMgmtReason;
}
$addAccount = $newAccount | ConvertTo-Json;

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://$Environment/PasswordVault/API  -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $addAccount -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: Define `$headers` as a simple hashtable w/o converting it to JSON. If that doesn't help, please update your question with the full error message.

Comment: Still receive the same error. I edited it above.

Comment: Please read again. If you're still getting that error you clearly did not do what I asked you to do.